# Why jquery mobile that return from php, it doesn't work?

Tags: jquery-mobile

**test1.html**

```
  <script>$(function(){
$.get(
    "test1.php",{},function(result){
    //$("#result").html(result);
    $("#result").html(result);
});});</script><div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>    
<div data-role="content">
<div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

**test1.php**

`<?
echo "<a href='#' id='btn_del' data-role='button' data-inline='true' data-icon='delete'>Del</a>";
?>`

It don't show button,but It just show hyperlink.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the jquery embedding into your button...

**refresh()**
update the form button in jquery mobile.

If you manipulate a form button via JavaScript, you must call the refresh method on it to update the visual styling.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-refresh

Comment: I've tried already by insert $("#btn_del").button("refresh"), but It still dosen't work.

Comment: have you implemented it inside document.ready or anything like, i think problem is the way of loading the script...